# NO right-click at all on touchpad after installing 14.10

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 14.10

Can someone help me please?

I cannot right-click pressing right corner(side) of my touchpad. I can do it only by clicking the right-key button on my keyboard.  I had no problem with it before upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10. Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
Option "ClickPad"         "true"
Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
```

in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf

Something like this:

Section "InputClass"

```
Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
MatchDriver "synaptics"
Option "ClickPad"         "true"
Option "EmulateMidButtonTime" "0"
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
```

EndSection